# Limit Logback Email to Enrivonment

Tags: java, logback, smtpappender

Although the Java project I'm working with contains different jconfig XML files per environment, it has one logback XML file for the entire project.

Inside, there is an SMTPAppender like:

```
    <appender name="ERROR_EMAIL" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>ERROR</level>
        </filter>
        <SMTPHost>${logs.smtp.host}</SMTPHost>
        <To>@abc.com</To>
        <From>123@abc.com</From>
        <Subject>[Error occurred in ${environment}</Subject>
    </appender>
```

As you see, access to the *environment* variable is available so can this be utilized to only send this ERROR_EMAIL in certain environments?

Thank you very much for your time!